# Error while requiring a file situated in another folder in Yii

Tags: php, yii

When I am trying to refer a file named AndroidNotificationPush.php using require in another file.

Why am I getting this error:

require_once(/home/Abhi/mango/siweb/protected/modules/rest/v10/components/helpers/AndroidPushNotification.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied ?

Comment: you probably don't have permissions to read that folder or file. I suggest you check for file permissions for the folder or file first.

Comment: No....I think I have permissions for that file.

Comment: Can you post what all permissions the file is having and from which user are you trying to access it?

Comment: I have given the file all permissions (chmod 777)...

Comment: Check files ownership. Application user and groups should be set properly.

Comment: Thanks......It worked